# How to run GTest (GoogleTest) for C/C++ application in Xcode 12 and macOS Big Sur 11

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, googletest

I have setup little project in `Xcode 12` on my `macOS Big Sur` to run my tiny math library, but now I want to test if it is working correctly. For that I chose `GTest` - *Google Testing Framework* aka `googletest`. It would be nice if someone told me how to execute it, so that I could make my first test suite?

math.hpp

```cpp
class Vector {
public:
    float x, y;
};

class Point {
public:
    float x, y;
    Point AddVector(Vector v);
};
```

math.cpp

```cpp
#include "math.hpp"

Point Point::AddVector(Vector v) {
    Point p2;
    p2.x = this->x + v.x;
    p2.y = this->y + v.y;
    return p2;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to skip boring stuff, you can just `brew install googletest`

- Ensure you have `xcode-select --install`'ed on your system (`git`, `clang` and other goodies)
- Install `CMake` - `googletest` way of generating `make`file build - simply called a buildsystem
- clone git repository from github.com - `git clone https://github.com/google/googletest.git -b release-1.10.0`
- Then:

```
cd googletest        # Main directory of the cloned repository.
mkdir build          # Create a directory to hold the build output.
cd build
cmake ..             # Generate native build scripts for GoogleTest.
make
sudo make install    # Install in /usr/local/ by default
```

- You want this to work **in Xcode**, so now it would be great time to visit your project settings.
- Click `File > New > Target`, choose `Command Line Tool`, name it to something memorable like `MainTest`, pick your project from drop-down menu and language to be **C++** here.
- From left pane, choose your project and then from targets pick the one newly created, go to `build settings`, and search for `header search paths`, add new row with `/usr/local/include/` - path to your libraries (*you may even be more selective and only add `/usr/local/include/gtest`*)
- In the same tab, `build settings`, search for `other linker flags` and add row with `-l gtest` linker flag
- Last Xcode configuration step is just to add `/usr/local/lib` to your `library search paths` in the same, `build settings` tab.
- Revisit all above steps where you added path, `library search paths`, and `header search paths`, to make sure they are set **to be recursive** - *otherwiese specify absolute path to library/header file*

In the last step, you should already have everything set-up properly, it's just a matter of writing your `test files` and a `test-runner`.

For a test you should employ a red-green-refactor principle, so I will provide you with a failing test:

```
//math_test.cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <math.h>

namespace  {
TEST(TestingTest, AddVector) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 2);
}
}
```

and a test runner, in the simplest form, should look like this:

```
//main.cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, (char**)argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```